# Can FOTA be performed by changing the execution point of the code i.e, changing the program counter in lpc1759

Tags: microcontroller, memory, flash, lpc, non-volatile-memory

For FOTA can we divide the memory into two blocks, eg : block A and block B.
And whenever there is a new version of firmware detected, we shall change the **execution point of the code**.

Is this feasible?

Comment: "Yes" What sort of an answer do you expect from a question like that? What have you tried, what have you looked at?

Comment: I have looked at bootloader for this method, there will be a static bootloader at adress 0x00000000 to 0x20000000. So when ever there is an update this bootloader will install the new frimware from the address 0x20000000.

Comment: You're very much skimping on the details, but 0x20000000 (512MB) does not sound right for the bootloader size.

Comment: Okay. I have an idea and yet to implement it, so still in the process therefore i can explain what i know now. Ill get back when i am literally stuck. Thank you for the advice's.